# Always displaying dialog as Unsupported Password Stores while launching eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I am getting an 3 dialog box while launching eclipse.
whats the problem with my SVN? how to avoid this dialog?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What operating system you using ?

Comment: I am using Linux 10.04 and Eclipse 3.5.2.

Comment: Look at my answer and let me know whether that fixed your issue or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the library named "libsvn-java" from Synaptic package manager or you can use apt-get to install the same. Do this and restart eclipse and try again. It should probably work now.

[image]

Comment: i tried thala, but sill same. no progress. yeanna panalam boss.

Comment: therlaye machi.. venumna Mr.Nithyanadava kekalama ? :)

Comment: @PadmaKumar - Can you try libsvn-dev library ?

Comment: I installed and restarted my eclipse. but I cant find the Subversion Native Lib Not Avil error dialog in my quest screen 3. But I am still getting the first 2 error screen Unsupported password stores.